# Sync files between two remote hosts using ansible sync module

Tags: ansible

When i am trying use the sync push module getting the below error

```
fatal: [node-master]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "sshpass -d20 /usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsync-path=sudo rsync --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L /home/hadoop/test rsync://node1/home/hadoop/test", "msg": "@ERROR: Unknown module 'home'\nrsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1649) [sender=3.1.2]\n", "rc": 5}
```

sample yaml file for sync push module

```
- name: Copy the file from node-master to node1 using Method Push
  ansible.posix.synchronize:
     mode: push
     src: /home/hadoop/test
     dest: rsync://node1/home/hadoop/test
```

Comment: Please add a question, explain what you tried, how you tried (task code could be useful), format the output (I did it for you)

Comment: Also check at the documentation (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html) if one of the example match your use case and if you're using the module correctly.

Comment: From the error message, you're trying to copy a file from node1 but the file doesn't exists there.

Comment: @zigarn the file is exist in the target node..i am using sync push module to get the file from target host to node1...
and please find below sample code

Comment: @zigarn
---
- name: Sync Pull task - Executed on  the Destination host
  hosts: workernodes
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Copy the file from mwiapp01 to mwiapp02 using Method Pull
      tags: sync-pull
      synchronize:
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: "{{ item }}"
        mode: pull
      delegate_to: node-master
     # register: syncfile
      #run_once: true
      with_items:
       - "/home/hadoop/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh"

Comment: When people ask for more information it's better to *edit your question* instead of leaving information in the comments (as you can see, comments don't allow for proper code formatting, making your last update almost illegible).

Comment: From your code and the output you're pulling from the current host of the play (node1) to the delegate host (node-master). From your comment, it seems you want the opposite. If it's the case, just remove the `mode: pull` will push from node-master to node1 (exactly as documented in the example "Synchronization of src on delegate host to dest on the current inventory host" of the doc)

Comment: @zigarn
As per the ansible documentation i ran the playbook and getting the below error.Do we need to setup anything on remote hosts for rync

fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "sshpass -d20 /usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsync-path=sudo rsync --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L rsync://node-master/home/hadoop/test /home/hadoop/test", "msg": "@ERROR: Unknown module 'home'\nrsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1649) [Receiver=3.1.2]\n", "rc": 5}

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the new ansible code and output?

Comment: @zigarn..i edited console output and code